# This inside $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I have encountered the following problem:

```
    function Conclude (thing){
        this.quant = thing.find('#quantity_material').val();
        this.thing = thing;
        this.material =[];
        this.finish = [];
        this.make = function (){
            var i=0;
            this.thing.each(function(){
                this.material [i]= $(this).find('#material_val').val();
                //Conclude.material doesn't work either
                i++;
            });
        }
    }
```

I want to assign `conclude.material` the values of an input out of several tables so that `conclude.material[1]` is value of `#material_val` from the first table and so on. The problem is that when I write this, it doesn't refer to function `conclude` inside `.each()`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: probably javascript, using jquery.

Comment: javascript with jquery

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` / context inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every `function` statement in JS gets its own `this` variable. You have two functions, one is called `Conclude` and the other one is an anonymous function (there are two anonymous functions really, but the thing I'm about to explain applies still).

Your error is here:

`this.thing.each(function(){` -> the `this` does not "belong" to `Conclude` function. It belongs to the anonymous function.

Easiest way out, at least for you, is to change the scope of anonymous function so that `this` in anonymous function refers to the outer, `Conclude` function. Seeing you are using `jQuery` already, use `jQuery.proxy` method to do so.

Code:

```
function Conclude (thing){
    this.quant = thing.find('#quantity_material').val();
    this.thing = thing;
    this.material =[];
    this.finish = [];   

    this.make = $.proxy(function (){
        this.thing.each($.proxy(function(index, item){
            this.material[index] = $(item).find('#material_val').val();             

        }, this));
    }, this);
}
```

Comment: @maze-le - well, that's one of the language rules, and by them - we must abide. I agree it's counter-intuitive at first, but with experience comes the muscle memory as well :)

Comment: the `$(this).find('#material_val')` in the each loop here will refer to the Conclude object, so you will need to alter the function args line in the example to `this.thing.each($.proxy(function(index, item) {` and then `$(this)` to `$(item)`. (note: also by adding the index arg you can remove the `var i = 0` and `i++` and use the `index` arg instead of `i`

Answer (score 4):

Try this one, pretty simple.

```
     function Conclude (thing){
       var _this = this;
       this.quant = thing.find('#quantity_material').val();
       this.thing = thing;
       this.material =[];
       this.finish = [];
       this.make = function (){
        var i=0;
        this.thing.each(function(){
            _this.material [i]= $(this).find('#material_val').val();

            i++;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You can make this better by altering `this.thing.each(function(){` to `this.thing.each(function(index){`. use the `index` instead of `i` and remove the variable and increment